# Minecraft importing zip maps not working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I download a ZIP minecraft map and import it into my minecraftworlds folder, a new entry appears in my minecraft worlds list, however the name is blank, the creation date is 01/01/70 and the map appears to be a default island, not related to the map i have downloaded. any ideas how to install these maps

I am on Windows 10 edition.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this helps.

> In file explorer, navigate to your `.zip` file. At the top, go to view and make sure "File name extensions" is checked. Right-click on your `.zip` file and click rename. Take away ".zip", and change it to ".mcworld". Open your `.mcworld` file, and Minecraft will open. After it says that it imported the level, go to your worlds and it should be there.

Comment: This answer is correct, but quick note: just put this file on the desktop, and then double click it. Once it is done loading in Minecraft you can just delete it. Just wanted to address this since the question said they had put the file in their world folder.